# IIS URL Redirect failing

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I need to redirect URLs of the form:

http://server1.name.here/path1/path2/?num=123456

to:

http://server2.name.here/path3/path2/?num=123456

using the IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0 on IIS 8.5.  I've used a DNS alias to handle the server name redirection.

I've been using the user interface to configure the path rewrite but despite trying several variations and extensive research I cannot get my rewrite to work, which is slightly embarrassing as I feel this should be a simple rewrite.  The web.config produced by the URL rewite user interface is:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="path rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="path1/path2/" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="num=[0-9]+" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="path3/path2/" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When I try to open server1.name.here/path1/path2/?num=123456 I get a "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." and the logs show no evidence that my URL is being rewritten or even flagged by the rewrite rule.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, can anyone enlighten me as to what I've got wrong?

Many Thanks Eden